# regex for feedburner name

Tags: regex, feedburner

I want to get the feed name from feedburner feed url. I'm trying this:

```
$feed = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/name';
$pattern = '~(?:http|https|)(?::\/\/|)?feeds.feedburner\.com/(?:clip:)?(\w+)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $feed, $feed_name);
```

and this:

```
$feed = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/name';
$pattern = '/http:\/\/feeds.feedburner.com\//';
$feed_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $feed);
```

And other variations but nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of regex, it is better to use [`parse_url` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$feed = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/name';
$arr = parse_url($feed);
echo $arr['path']; /name
```